# Is there a hack to be able to run the current line or selection in RStudio without moving the cursor?

Tags: r, rstudio

**UPDATE (April 2013):** As per [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15848337/180892), RStudio no longer jumps cursor on selection.

---

I'm running RStudio 0.97.168.

I like to use the script editor in RStudio like a console. Thus, I run a line of code and then edit it a little bit and re-run it. I often also explore objects by selecting some of the code and running the selection and then progressively altering the selection. At present RStudio always moves the cursor after running a line of code. The cursor can move to a variety of places. Typically the cursor moves to the next line of R code, but depending on the context, it could move to the end of the code block or the next line. It's really frustrating having to  constantly move the cursor back to where I want it.

While I often appreciate the default cursor movement behaviour, I'd  like to have the option to run the selection or the current line without the cursor moving.
I've raised this as a [suggestion on RStudio support](http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/suggestions/1762-option-to-retain-selection-after-running-selected-r-code).

I'd like to be able to have a shortcut key like "Cmd+Alt+Enter" that runs the current line or selection and does not move the cursor in the script editor.
I realise that this is not currently supported, but **I was wondering whether there might be some creative hack that could enable the cursor not to move after running a command or even a patch or perhaps some sort of external macro.**

Comment: CTRL + SHIFT + P? It reruns the same region, too.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen But you still have to run the region once and then move the cursor back for that to work

Comment: Thanks. I suppose I could be more creative with Ctrl+Shift+P. I.e., it works well for continually running a single line/region of code. But that's not quite the behaviour that I want. I often want to be able to quickly change the size of the selection (e.g., to inspect an object within a line of code) or continue editing the line of code.

Comment: @Dason Yes, but it will rerun the same region continuously after you've made changes which is nice. So ctrl+enter once, then make changes ctrl+shift+p (doesn't move), make changes, ctrl+shift+p (doesn't move).. etc.

Comment: @JeromyAnglim Switching back and forth to the console and the script window with Ctrl+1 / Ctrl+2 may be more effective for inspecting objects (I'm assuming you mean something like str(),head(), tail(), typeof(), summary(), or some such?)

Comment: @Brandon I have a few issues with the console option. (1) the console in general and the RStudio console in particular has very different text editing shortcut keys to the script editor. In particular I use vim keybindings in the terminal, which aren't available in RStudio console. Thus, I always feel like I'm slowing to a crawl in the RStudio console. (2) often my script editor includes exactly the code that I want to run; in fact part of what I want to do is check that I haven't made any typos in my code; it's simpler to just highlight the code and see that it returns the intended result.

Comment: @JeromyAnglim Have you tried vim mode? `Tools > Options > (End of list) Enable vim mode`

Comment: I use vim editing mode all the time in the editor. It's great. But it don't think it works in the console. When I press escape in the console, the contents of the console disappear rather than changing the editing mode.

Comment: cue the wickham re-invention of Emacs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to version 0.98.83 of RStudio using the [daily build](http://www.rstudio.org/download/daily/desktop/) section.

It appears that at some point in recent versions of RStudio, the cursor no longer jumps when code is run from a selection in the script window.

That's great news.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who ends up here in 2020:

- **Ctrl(or Cmd) + Enter:** Will run current line and jump to the next one. If a code portion is selected, run the selected code without jumping further.
- **Alt + Enter:** – Will run the current line of code without moving the cursor to the next line, useful if you want to run it multiple times.

([Source](https://appsilon.com/r-studio-shortcuts-and-tips/))

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of flexibility, I suggest you use the editor `Sublime Text 2`, add in the package installer by Will Bond and then install the `SublimeREPL` package which will allow you to use an R interpreter within ST2 (or BASH prompt, Python / Ruby / whatever interpeter, concurrently if you wish).

You can then alternate between your code and the interpreter without lifting your fingers from the keyboard *and* your cursor will be at the same point every time when you want to switch back.

Sublime Text will also allow you to write a custom keybinding to automate this task.

I cannot recommend using Sublime Text 2 highly enough when coding for R. You can even pass files directly from ST2 into RStudio very easily if you like using the plot panes (very easy to do with the `SidebarEnhancements` package in ST2).

RStudio is awesome for many things -- especially now with Knitr, builds etc etc. But ST2 with an R REPL is many orders of magnitude more powerful for general code writing / editing than RStudio.

Sorry it's not RStudio specific, but it is a nice workaround!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, there are many other text editor options which would permit the form of interaction that I desire (e.g., Vim with R plugin, Emacs+ESS, and many more). I've tried the complete customisation route with R and Vim, but I generally prefer the RStudio environment. Thus, the lack of one feature is not enough to make me leave RStudio.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for all you've published re: R elsewhere. Sorry I couldn't be as helpful to you as you've been to me along the way!

Comment: No worries :-) I hope my response didn't come across as unfriendly. I'm just really keen to find a solution in RStudio.

Comment: Not in the slightest. Hope someone turns up something tractable.